# MySQL service error 1607, when starting the service

Tags: mysql, windows, service

i just can't figure out this problem. When i want to start the Mysql service from services.msc then i get this error:
[MySQL service error 1067 windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJdZe.png)

I tried also something like net start on command. Nothing works!

Comment: Look in the event viewer for errors.

Comment: Where i can find that logs?

Comment: run eventvwr.msc

Comment: Some pics: http://imgur.com/yOH2o01  http://imgur.com/9ts2hRZ `Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data\LAPTOP-CEOUJ0B7.lower-test`

Comment: Find the earliest MySQL related error then google for the error message.  (or just try reinstalling it)

Comment: Thank you. But i don't want to reinstalling the MySQL. I have tons of websites on Webmatrix. They can not connect to the database because the service can't start. But i will google for the error: `Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error`

Comment: If i change the path from MySQL service to the Xampp MySQL path: `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql` then the service starting! So basically there is a problem with MYSQLD.exe and my.ini file from the default Mysql Webmatrix. Someone can help my?